# Fugenlaut in "Frühjahresferien" versus "Frühjahrsferien"

Tags: compound, interfix

In [einer SO-Frage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74073026/4299358) ist mir folgendes Deutsch untergekommen:

> Wenn Du meinen Blog in den letzten Monaten gelesen hast, wirst Du wissen, dass ich im März diesen Jahres während meiner **Frühjahresferien** zwei Wochen lang durch Europa gereist bin.

Der [Fugenlaut *»-es«*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut) ist mir bisher nicht groß aufgefallen, obwohl mir Komposita wie *»Jahreszeit«* und *»Geistesblitz«* sofort als Beispiele einfallen. Bei *»Frühjahresferien«* klingt es mir jedoch ungewohnt (Hochdeutsch, Deutschland) - meiner Meinung nach müsste es statt *»-es«* nur den Fugenlaut *»-s«* geben, weil die Wörter *»Frühjahr«* und *»Ferien«* zusammenkommen sollen und nicht *»früh«* und *»Jahresferien«* (klingt wie eine Schülerversion aus *»Jahresurlaub«*, aber im Gegensatz zu Urlaub können Ferien nie verfallen oder noch "übrig" sein). Trotzdem kennt [Wikipedia die Frühjahr**s***ferien*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schulferien#Oster-/Fr%C3%BChjahrs-/Fr%C3%BChlingsferien).

[dict.leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Wortbildungsregeln/Komposition/WB-Elements/Fuge-es.xml?lang=de#2.2.6.5) meint dazu:

> Das Fugenelement es kann nach männlichen und sächlichen Nomen stehen, die eine Genititivform mit es haben. Das Fugenelement es wird in der Regel nur nach einfachen Nomen verwendet, d. h. nicht nach Ableitungen mit einem Suffix und nicht nach Komposita.

Nur leider ist *»Frühjahr«* weder eine Ableitung, noch ein Kompositum, sondern ein eigenständiges Wort. Aber auch nicht unbedingt "*einfach*." Gegenbeispiele:

- der Frühjahr**s**putz
- die Frühjahr**s**müdigkeit
- das Frühjahr**s**hochwasser

Alle ohne Binde-e. Sind mir auch nie mit einem *e* untergekommen. Ich könnte sogar argumentieren, dass bei periodischen Dingen auch ein reines Binde-e durchaus sinnvoll ist (*Frühjahr**e**putz* = man putzt alle Frühjahre), nur ist das lediglich unüblich.

- Kann man sich das an noch anderen Beispielen ableiten, oder sind beide Fugenlaute gleichwertig legal?
- Ist in diesem einen Fall ein Binde-s bloß weitverbreiteter und die Kombination aus Binde-e und Binde-s nur regional geprägt (z.B. Schweiz oder Österreich), aber jetzt zufällig mir so untergekommen?

Comment: Ich kann deiner Logik nicht ganz folgen. Du sagst selbst, dir fallen sofort Komposita wie `Jahreszeit` ein. Im Deutschen wird sich oft nach dem letzten Wort in einem Kompositum gerichtet (der Artikel richtet sich danach und nur das letzte Wort wird dekliniert). Warum sollte es dann nicht Frühjahresferien sein, wenn es schon Jahreszeit ist.

Comment: Weil es auch den _Frühjahr**s**putz_, das _Frühjahr**s**hochwasser_ und die _Frühjahr**s**müdigkeit_ ohne e gibt. Wikipedia kennt sogar [Frühjahr**s**_ferien_](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schulferien#Oster-/Frühjahrs-/Frühlingsferien), aber eben auch ohne e.

Comment: Macht Sinn, ich denke das könntest du noch in deinen OP editieren, damit das klarer wird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Klar ist, dass es das Wort "Frühjahrsferien" (ohne *e*) gibt, und dass das die weitaus geläufigere Variante ist. Im DWDS kann man solche Worthäufigkeiten nachsehen und das nachvollziehen: Fast niemand benutzt "Frühjahr**e**sferien", im [Zeitungskorpus gibt es zwei Fundstellen in 70 Jahren](https://www.dwds.de/r/plot/?view=1&corpus=zeitungenxl&norm=date%2Bclass&smooth=spline&genres=0&grand=1&slice=1&prune=0&window=3&wbase=0&logavg=0&logscale=0&xrange=1946%3A2022&q1=Fr%C3%BChjahrsferien&q2=Fr%C3%BChjahresferien).

Aber man kann im Deutschen natürlich Wörter auch selbst zusammensetzen, solange das Ergebnis für die Adressaten verständlich ist und der deutschen Grammatik entspricht. Beides ist bei "Frühjahresferien" m.E. der Fall. "Frühjahr" kann man, nach Jahrhunderten im Gebrauch, schon als "einfaches Wort" sehen. Falsch ist das Wort "Frühjahresferien" also auch nicht.

Es bleibt die Frage, wozu man eine neue Zusammensetzung baut, wenn es schon eine weit verbreitete gibt. Konkret auf den Blog bezogen vermute ich, dass sich der Autor einfach an Wörtern wie "Jahresurlaub" orientiert hat, ohne groß darüber nachzudenken.

Comment: DWDS ist mit der Funktion noch spitzer als bisher schon! War mir neu.

Answer (score 0):

Das empfinde ich schon fast als falsch, aber würde den Unterschied vielleicht gar nicht  hören. Andere Beispiele sind mir daher nicht bekannt.

Hier (bei mir jedenfalls) liegt ein vokalische R vor (Tiefschwa), was von der Betonung der Silbe abhängen kann, so dass eine schwache Silbe assimiliert wird, wenn *Früh-* am Anfang steht. Insofern stimmt der Ansatz zumindest, dass es sich um *ein* Wort handelt. Es betrifft also auch *Frühja'* vs *Jahr* ganz unabhängig von der Endung.

> Nur leider ist »Frühjahr« weder eine Ableitung, noch ein Kompositum, sondern ein eigenständiges Wort. Aber auch nicht unbedingt "einfach."

Es ist vielfältig. Die Wortstämme sind einfach für sich lexikalisiert und ergeben den Sinn als Summe des Ganzen. Die Bindeglieder der Fügung sind dabei sicherlich phonetisch selektiert, sodass die morpho-syntaktische Funktion pragmatischer Weise dahingestellt bleiben kann.

> regional geprägt (z.B. Schweiz oder Österreich)

Ich vermute mal das wäre der Grund für das gefundene Zitat. Oberdeutsch ist je aus Mittelhochdeutsch hervorgegangen und pflegt einen hochdeutschen Stil neben den ländlichen Varietäten.

Im Gegenteil könnte ich also geneigt sein, um das R zu betonen, einen Fugenlaut (orthografisch -e-) vor dem Fall (-s-) einzufügen damit der Konsonant an einem Silbenanfang steht und richtig konsonantisches ausgesprochen werden kann (siehe so ähnlich die aus etymologischer Sicht unfreiwillig komische Trennung *Le-gas-the-nik-er* weil *-ste-* sonst zu *scht* würde).